# ML inequality for $ \int \frac{1}{z^2-1} \, dz $

Tags: inequality, contour-integration, complex-integration, triangle-inequality

Prove, using ML inequality (estimation lemma), that $$\left |\int f(z) \, dz\right| < \frac{π}3 \,,$$ where $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-1}\,,$$  over the arc of the circle $|z|=2$ that lies in the first quadrant.

So the length of the contour is π, but I can't get a suitable upper bound for $|f(z)|$. After factorising the denominator and using reverse triangle inequality for both fractions, I just get $$\left|\frac{1}{z-1}\right| \le 1 $$ and $$\left|\frac{1}{z+1}\right| \le 1 $$, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $|z_1-z_2|\ge ||z_1|-|z_2||$ (See [This Article](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality/Complex_Numbers#Corollary_1)),  we have on $|z|=2$

$$\left|\frac1{z^2-1}\right|\le \frac{1}{\left||z|^2-1\right|}=\frac1{3}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Omg thank you, it never dawned to me not to factorize the denominator but just use the reverse triangle inequality outright.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  ;-)